# Unwanted label on launching screen in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, label, launch

When I'm launching my app, it shows white screen with unwanted label (on launch screen, not on the initial view). I set the launch images to be just white images, but now the label started appearing and I don't know where it comes from. How can I delete it?[image: I attach a screenshot]

Comment: Have you checked there is no label on your LaunchScreen.storyboard file?

Comment: I don't have the LaunchScreen.storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you started using the `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. Inside your project there are two storyboards, the `Main.storyboard` and the `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. Go on this one and delete the label.

Comment: There is no LaunchScreen.storyboard. Only "main".

Comment: Right click the only storyboard that you have, Open As>Source Code, Command+F and search for label. If you found something, there is a label in your storyboard and if you understand the struct of source code you can delete. Just delete from <label until </label>

Answer (score 0):

Debug the UI and see in which class the Label is present. Then delete it from that class/xib. If at all you don't find Label in UI debug also then delete your storyboard and add it again.

[image]

Comment: I searched through the entire xcode and there was no such label.

Comment: How did you debug UI?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by debug UI. I just searched the entire xcode using command+shift+f.

Comment: You need to put breakpoints somewhere in code (may be applicationDidFinishLaunching:) before launching the app and once you are into debug mode, click on the icon shown in screenshot. Then you can see your label in UI debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Info.plist` file and make sure you got rid of the property `UILaunchStoryboardName` (it appears under the name "Launch screen interface file base name.") There might be a LaunchScreen.xib or LaunchScreen.storyboard you have floating around. Then make sure you set the Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name in your project settings.